# Setting Value in Javascript with encoded HTML

Tags: javascript, html

Quick question, I have a simple javascript problem that I don't know the fix to.

```
divNext = document.getElementById("submit_button");
if(document.getElementById("page").value == 4 ? divNext.value = 'Submit' : divNext.value = 'Next &#187;');
```

Now the problem is that it should display the Next with two >> after it (at least if they where encoded) however it displays them with the actual content there. How can I get it to display the html encoded character?

Comment: Exactly what sort of element is "submit_button", @Craig?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because you have HTML-encoded the character instead of encoding it to be in a Javascript string.

And by the way, you are using both the `if` and the `?` conditional operator incorrectly.

```
divNext = document.getElementById("submit_button");
divNext.value = document.getElementById("page").value == 4 ? 'Submit' : 'Next \xBB';
```

Or using `if`:

```
divNext = document.getElementById("submit_button");
if (document.getElementById("page").value == 4) {
  divNext.value = 'Submit'
} else {
  divNext.value = 'Next \xBB';
}
```

Comment: @Pointy: Or an `input` element with `type="button"` or `type="submit"` which is more likely.

Comment: So when doing this in JavaScript I need JavaScript "Encoded" characters I take it. Thanks =). Accidentally forgot to take off the if when converted it from using the if statement to the ternary operator.

Answer (score 0):

Just put them in

```
document.getElementById("page").value == 4 ? divNext.value = 'Submit' : divNext.value = 'Next >>');
```

or use `.innerHTML`

```
document.getElementById("page").value == 4 ? divNext.innerHTML = 'Submit' : divNext.innerHTML = 'Next &#187;&#187;');
```

Also, if you are using the ternary operator why do you have an `if`?

Comment: Good question - that statement is messed up.

Comment: You are using the conditional (ternary) operator is if it was a statement, not an operator.